# The input field could not show the expected result that I filled in Django

Tags: python, html, django

**customer/update_order.html**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                <form method="POST" action=".">
                {% csrf_token %} 
                <tr>
                    <th style="width:160px;text-align:center;background-color: blue;color:red;">食物</th>
                    <th style="width:100px;text-align:center;background-color: blue;color:red;">單價</th>
                    <th style="width:100px;text-align:center;background-color: blue;color:red;">數量</th>
                    <th style="width:100px;text-align:center;background-color: blue;color:red;">總價</th>
                    <th style="width:100px;text-align:center;background-color: blue;color:red;"></th>
                </tr>
                
                {% for item in food %}
             
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;">
                        {{ item.product.name }}
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;">$ {{ item.unit_price }}</td>
                    <td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;">
                        
                            <input name="qty{{ item.id }}" type="text" value="{{ item.quantity }}">
                     
                        
                    </td>
                    
                        <td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;">
                            <a href="{% url 'update_item_qty' item.id %}" class="btn btn-warning">更新</a>
                        </td>
                 
                    
                    <td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;">$ {{ item.total_price }}</td>
                    
                </tr>
             
                {% endfor %} 
              
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4" align="left" class="upline"><strong>總計</strong></td>
                    <td align="center" class="upline">$ {{ order.total_price }} (包括$100運費)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4" align="left" class="upline"><strong>換領積分</strong></td>
                    <td align="center" class="upline">{{ order.points_earned }}</td>
                </tr>
            </form>
            </table>
```

**views.py**

```
def update_order(request,order_id):
    global cartlist_update
    order = Order.objects.get(id=order_id)
    food = OrderDetail.objects.filter(order=order)
    cartlist_update = []
    for item in food:
        cart = []
        menu_food = Menu.objects.get(name=item.product.name)
        food_name = OrderDetail.objects.get(product=menu_food)
        cart.append(food_name.product.name)
        cart.append(food_name.unit_price)
        cart.append(food_name.quantity)
        cart.append(food_name.total_price)
        print(cart)
        cartlist_update.append(item)
    print(cartlist_update)
    
    
    context = {'order':order,'food':food}
    return render(request,'customer/update_order.html',context)
        
def update_item_qty(request,item_id):
    global cartlist_update
    
    menu = OrderDetail.objects.get(id=item_id)
    print(menu.id)
    qty_id = 'qty'+str(menu.id)
    print(qty_id)
    new_quantity = request.POST.get(qty_id,'')
    print(new_quantity)
    order_id = menu.order.id
##    original_food = menu.product.name
    price = menu.unit_price
    
    return redirect('update_order',order_id=order_id)
```

**models.py**

```
class Driver(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)
##    orders = models.ManyToManyField('Order',related_name='driver_orders')
    mobile = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
    approval = models.BooleanField(default=False)
##    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='staff_profile/',null=True,blank=True)
##    points = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,null=True,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Menu(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant,models.CASCADE)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='menu/')
    
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=7)
    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Order(models.Model):
    PAYMENT_OPTIONS = (
        ('VISA','VISA'),
        ('Master','Master'),
        ('Octopus','Octopus'),
        ('Cash','Cash'),
    )
    STATUS = (
        ('Pending','Pending'),
        ('Approved','Approved'),
        ('On the way','On the way'),
        ('Delivered','Delivered'),
        ('Completed','Completed'),
    )
    METHODS = (
        ('外賣自取','外賣自取'),
        ('送遞','送遞'),
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    customer = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
    card_id = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=10,null=True,blank=True)
    mobile = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
    total_price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=7)
    payment_method = models.CharField(max_length=50,choices=PAYMENT_OPTIONS,null=True,blank=True)
    driver = models.ForeignKey(Driver,models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50,choices=STATUS,default='Pending')
    take_method = models.CharField(max_length=50,choices=METHODS,null=True,blank=True)
    points_earned = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=350,null=True,blank=True)

##    def save(self,commit=True):
##        new_order = super(Order,self).save(commit=False)
##        new_order.code = 'K00'+str(self.new_order.id)
##        if commit:
##            new_order.save()
        
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.customer)+'\'s Order'
    
class OrderDetail(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order,models.CASCADE)
    product =  models.ForeignKey(Menu,models.CASCADE)
    unit_price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    total_price = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.order.customer)+'\'s --- '+str(self.product.name)+' x '+str(self.quantity)
```

I am trying to run the `update_item_qty` view after I click the hyperlink. However if I try to print out the result with `request.POST.get('qty'+str(menu.id),'')`, it returns empty instead of the value that I put on the input field name called `'qty'+str(menu.id)` even though I had included the form inside. Can anyone show me where is the problem?

Comment: Can anyone help please?

Comment: Please provide a minimalworking example next time as explained in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Can you update your the question with `driver` and `menu` model?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the variables in the POST request by looping all key value pairs in your post request.

**views.py**

```
def update_item_qty(request,item_id):
    # Loop over all key value pairs in the POST request.
    for k, v in request.POST.items():

        # Check if the key starts with qty
        if k.startswith('qty'):
            
            # Get the item id and the quantity
            item_id = k.split('qty')[1]
            quantity = v 
            print(f'The item {item_id} has the quantity {v}.'}
```

Comment: So should I use ```if request.method == 'POST'``` or use the form action?

Comment: The form action is already set to POST. I edited the answer to specify in which files the code should be placed.

Comment: How about if I am using for loop in the template? Because if for loop the input name must be different

Comment: You don't have to use a for loop. The name attribute of the input should not be a variable, so you can always access it in your **views.py**.

Comment: I mean each of the input fields is inside ```{% for item in food %}``` loop

Comment: Sorry I was not aware of the for loop, I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: I tried the answer but still does not work